# All the content in the MDDialog is overlapping

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I tried adding adaptive_height to kv in gridlayout but it made the overlapping much worse.
and tried using other layout but then placement becomes difficult.

.KV code

```
<Settings_Dialog>
    rows: 4
    adaptive_height: True
    
    MDLabel:
        text: 'App Settings'
        font_size: 15

    MDGridLayout:
        cols: 2
        rows: 1
        MDLabel:
            text: 'App Theme'
            font_size: 10
        ToggleButton:
            id: darklight
            text: {'normal':'LIGHT', 'down':'DARK'}[self.state]
            color: {'normal':[0,0,0], 'down':[1,1,1]}[self.state]
            background_color: {'normal':[1,1,1,1], 'down':[0,0,0,1]}[self.state]
            font_size: self.height * .6
            on_press: print(self.state)
            size_hint: 0.2, 0.8

    MDLabel:
        text: 'Plot Settings'
        font_size: 15

    MDGridLayout:
        rows: 3
        cols: 2

        MDLabel:
            text: "Plot Type"
            font_size: 10
        MDDropDownItem:
            id: g_type
            text: 'Candle'
            font_size: 10
            #current_item: 'Candle'
            on_release: root.plot_type.open()
        MDLabel:
            text: 'Plot Color'
            font_size: 10
        MDDropDownItem:
            id: g_color
            text: 'Default'
            font_size: 10
            #current_item: 'Default'
            on_release: root.plot_color.open()
        MDLabel:
            text: 'Volume'
            font_size: 10
        MDSwitch:
            active: True
            size_hint: 0.3,0.8
```

.py code part

```
class MainScreen(MDScreen):
    def settings(self):
        close_button = MDFlatButton(
            text = 'Close',
            font_size = 15,
            on_release = self.close_settings,
            opacity = 0.5
        )
        save_button = MDFlatButton(
            text = 'Save Changes',
            font_size = 15,
            on_release = self.savee,
            opacity = 0.5
        )
        self.settings = MDDialog(
                    title = 'Settings',
                    auto_dismiss = False,
                    type = 'custom',
                    content_cls = Settings_Dialog(),
                    buttons = [save_button, close_button]
        )
        self.settings.open()
        
    def close_settings(self, obj):
        self.settings.dismiss()
    
    def savee(self, obj):
        self.settings.dismiss()

class Settings_Dialog(MDGridLayout):
    ##and have a few function in here but they don't do anything with size...
```

So, here basically MainScreen is my main screen then on a button press it calls the dialog.

image of the issue [you can see the close and switch overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylAHD.png)

SOLUTION:

Just put `adaptive_height: True` in all the objects

image now [the overlapping is gone.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9alQ1.png)

Comment: how did you create the dialog ?

Comment: i have updated it

Comment: Try setting size_hint:None,None

Comment: @ctrl7 where to put it?

Comment: Keep in mind that `adaptive_height: True` means the `GridLayout` will use the smallest height that will contain its children. It calculates that minimum based on the heights of its children, so to get a good value for its height, those children need to have explicit values for their heights. Otherwise, the height of that child will be counted as zero, leading to overlapping items or items outside the `GridLayout`.

Comment: @l3lackl3uck set size_hint:None,None to all the widgets that are overlapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put `adaptive_height: True` in all the objects